How to automatically highlight dynamic values in a thymeleaf template?
I would like to highlight the dynamic values (context variables) of a thymeleaf template, by say wrapping each one of them in a span and applying a yellow background.
For example, this thymeleaf:
<div th:if="${a} == 'a'" th:text="'hello ' + ${a}?${b}:${c}">

executed with context:
{
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
}

should output:
<div>hello <span style="background-color: yellow;">b</span></div>

The surrounding span with the background is what I would like to have automatically inserted around every printed variable.
Changing the values themselves (to add the wrapping span) doesn't work because the values can be used in conditionals within the template, so changing values can alter what those conditionals evaluate to.
Search and replace can yield false postives because dynamic values can also organically occur in the template.
I've also looked at thymeleaf processors and did not spot something that may help. Can this be achieved?

Can you give an example of how you want the Thymeleaf template to look and how the html output should look like?

Updated with example.

You're output makes no sense... according to your example Thymeleaf, it should output <div>hello a?b:c</div> why do you think it should output <div>hello <span style="background-color: yellow;">b</span></div>?

You are right, I have fixed the example. The surrounding span with the background is what I would like to have automatically inserted around every printed variable.

@Metroids do you see any way to achieve this?
